# Effects of a 20GB error.log for Apache

Tags: php, apache

I found an error log file that is 20GB in terms of size!

I wanted to know if it will be slow for Apache to write to this?

I ask because the way I understand it is that Apache opens the error_log file upon start and writes to it, which shouldn't be that slow - Is this true?

Or will this sort of file size reduce speed of logging errors?

Thanks all

Comment: why do you want to add to this error log file ?  Will you ever want to process all that information in one unit ?

Comment: I do not want to append to this log file. I am just trying to determine if this would be a reason for my application being slow as I am trying to identify a bottleneck.

Comment: more importantly, do you have errors you have to fix or are you under attack, or just poor admin not cleaning up occasionally?

Comment: @Will - yes tonnes of notices from another developer within for loops amplifying the number of lines logged. I just wanted to know if this would slow things down?

Comment: Fix/prevent the notices in those loops, and it will probably help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appending to a 20GB file costs the same amount as appending to a 0B file, so it won't slow Apache down.

It will be a pain to process that file, have you considered rotating your logs hourly?

Comment: Hourly is probably an overkill, i recommend daily and then see how that works out

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know he only appends the data so the size of the error log is of no immediate consequence, BUT what is a 20 GB Error log good for? You can't really find anything in it, i recommend you take a look at logrotate http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html

Answer (score 0):

Apache opens the log files when it starts up (and closes/reopens them when you send a HUP), and then keeps them open for the life of the server. As such, there's a one-time file opening and seeking cost, after which data is simply appended to the log.

Even if it was doing an open/seek/write/close operation, seeking to the end of a file is a relatively lightweight operation. Doing this hundreds or thousands of times a second (for a busy site) would start getting expensive.

20gig of error data, however, does seem excessive. That's a LOT of 404's and whatnot. Depending on how long you've had this log kicking around, you might want to go in with a machete and start weeding out some of the more obvious errors (like many repeated failed requests for robots.txt or favicon.ico returning 404s).

You can use Apache's own "[rotatelogs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html)" to automatically rotate things for you, or use the system's own log cleanup facilities.